# PHP PDO prepare statement for update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following is my attempt at a prepare statement. It is causing the page to die at the moment so obviously something is wrong.

```
function telephoneinsert($elector,$inputs,$outputs){
            global $dbh;
            $sql = "UPDATE electors SET $inputs WHERE ID=?";
            $q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($outputs,$elector));
            //UPDATE STATS
        }
```

That is the function called on page like this

```
telephoneinsert($Ielector,$inputs,$outputs);
```

Where $inputs = a posted array that if echoed looks like this `name = ?, type =?`. It is deliberately rtrim'd to get rid of the last comma.

Same principle with $outputs if echoed looks like `benjamin,socialist`

ERROR REPORTING SHOWING NOTHING

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
```

Comment: Do you have error_reporting turned on?  Does your PDO have its error reporting mode set properly?

Comment: I don't think so as its showing up nothing. $this->pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
  print_r($dbh->errorInfo());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$outputs` contains a comma-delimited string, but `execute()` expects parameters to be passed as elements of an array.  Therefore you must split the string apart:

```
$q->execute(explode(',', "$outputs,$elector"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your array here you have 2 elements

```
$q->execute(array($outputs,$elector));
```

but only one `?` in your sql, the number of array elements needs to match the number of question marks in sequence they occur

Comment: There is more than one question mark to match. Inputs contains a sting of any number of question marks $inputs = 'name = ?, type =?'

Comment: Why have you submitted a piece of my code here as an answer when clearly you haven't read the question.

Comment: @Robin Knight Actually, this answer is kind of correct, with the difference that `1` should be `3`...

Comment: because I was Illustrating that you didnt have enough question marks. I did it because I was trying to help you, jeroen is right it should be 3, but at the time you posted your question wasnt developed enough to show what was in $inputs. PS your comment is a bit abrupt. please be nice